# Maven jaxb generate plugin to read xsd files from multiple directories

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

If i have xsd file in the following directories

```
src/main/resources/xsd
src/main/resources/schema/common
src/main/resources/schema/soap
```

How can i instruct the maven jaxb plugin to generate jaxb classes using all schema files in the above directory? I can get it to generate the class files if i specify one of the folders but i cant get i dont know how to include all three folders.

Here is how i generate the files for one folder:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I tried adding multiple  entries in the  element but it just ignores all of them if i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

u can try this configuration :

```
<configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaIncludes>
        <include>xsd/*.xsd</include>
            <include>schema/*/*.xsd</include>
    </schemaIncludes>
</configuration>
```

source : http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide

Answer (score 2):

The plugin describes to put the schemata files into [src/main/resources](http://static.highsource.org/mjiip/maven-jaxb2-plugin/generate-mojo.html) and not into subfolders. I would recommend to use the defaults of the plugin in the sense of convention over configuration. Furthermore it's important having the schemata to include the correct files including the correct folders.

The best thing in such situations is having a separate module which contains only the schemata's and maybe some supporting classes.

Comment: Yes the problem i have is the schemas are in specific directories because they are organised by module. if i put them all in the same folder i will be including Jaxb classes where i dont need to.